# Remove seconds from time with strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I need to convert an hour given as a string to an hour (object) without seconds (HH: MM), in Python (it's for an assignment, so it must be string to object). The hour is input by the user. This is my code at the moment.:)

```
from datetime import datetime
start_hour = str(input("Enter starting hour: "))
start_str = start_hour
start_object = datetime.strptime(start_str, '%H:%M').time()
print(start_object)
```

So if the user enters 10:00, it must show as 10:00, not 10:00:00

EDIT: I've been messing around with the code and now have this.

```
def convertir_str_en_heure(heure):
    import datetime
    if heure and heure.strip():
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(heure,"%H:%M").time()
    else:
        return None
```

the input comes from the user in another function. The output must be in datetime.time, which is the case here, but without seconds. I'm still stuck there.

Comment: [`start_object.strftime(your_format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: btw this line is redundant `start_str = start_hour`

Comment: @Ch3steR IIUC he wants it a datetime object, not a string.

Comment: @Onur Hour object? Don't know what's that, I misread the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ch3steR _I need to convert an hour given as a string to an hour **(object)**_ Input will be a string. Edit: I think he means a date_time object (?)

Comment: There is no "hour" object in Python. The closest I can imagine is a `datetime.time` object, but that also has e.g. a `seconds` attribute. If this is just about how some data structure is *displayed*, use `strftime` to format to string

Comment: @aberkb you are right! Thank you for pointing that out. i've had my face in this program for too long now i think.

Comment: @MrFuppes I was going to try out your idea, but i had misread. The output cannot be a string. I think Onur might have it with his date_time object. The assignment says, in short, to convert a time given a string, to a hour formatted HH:MM. I have been googling and trying all sorts of solutions with different functions, to no avail. The closest I got to having an 'object' was this solution above with datetime. I'm sorry it's not clearer, since i'm a beginner the whole thing is a bit unclear to me as well. I'll start from Onur's comment with date_time object, might give me a lead.